# How can i use the example code to only Copy a part of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/CodeRomeos/402oLqrf/

I want to use the code below that works perfectly for copying text within a .  I want to change it to work on a two column table and only copy column 2.

Any help would be appreciated.  The working example is in the top link.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='copied'></div>

  <div class="copy-to-clipboard">
    <input readonly type="text" value="Click Me To Copy" readonly>
  </div>
</div>

$(function() {
  $('.copy-to-clipboard input').click(function() {
    $(this).focus();
    $(this).select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    $(".copied").text("Copied to clipboard").show().fadeOut(2500);
  });
});

.container {
  max-width: 25rem;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
  .copy-to-clipboard input {
    border: none;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .copied {
    position: absolute;
    background: #6ce890;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 99;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    font-size: .8rem;
  }
}


The code in the example above is what I want to use but instead of all the text in a <div> only make column 2 able to be copied.

So say the first row of a 2 column table has the following:

Column1                       Column2
Sometext column 1             Some text column 2

only copy Some text in Column 2 to the clipboard.
```

Comment: This is suppose to be a Question & Answer board. You didn't ask a question. You just stated what you wanted. If Stack Overflow was called "Stack Write My Code for Me Over and Over" do you think experienced software developers would spend time any time here helping people?  The whole point to SO is so you can work through a problem on which you are stuck.

Comment: Attitudes like this is why i RARELY come here.  Im new trying to learn.  Im gone

Comment: If you want to learn to write JavaScript, try writing it, and, only ask a question when your stuck. You will find that people like me will stop writing comments "with an attitude" (*Air Quotes)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you'll use a table structure, you can find the input in the adjacent cell with `$(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input')`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.copy-cell').click(function() {
    const other = $(this).next('td')
    other.find('input').focus();
    other.find('input').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    $(".copied").text("Copied to clipboard").show().fadeOut(2500);
  });
});
```

```css
.container td {
  max-width: 25rem;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
}

td.copy-cell {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.copied {
  position: absolute;
  background: #6ce890;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 99;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  font-size: .8rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="container">
  <tr>
    <td class='copy-cell'>
      Click on this
    </td>
    <td>
      <input readonly type="text" value="... to copy this" readonly>
      <div class='copied'></div>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thats what Im after but when using your code the cursor doesnt turn into a pointer to click on the second column. if you look at the example code in my first post the action of the pointer over the text is the final thing.  That way when you click it, the text highlights and the use knows what they clicked was copied.

Comment: ok, so in this example, you want the user to click in col A to select and copy col A - or click in col B to copy col B? I thought you wanted to click in col A to select and copy col B. Pls clarify

Comment: Also I cant get the padding between columns to get wider.  I would want the first column to be left justified then maybe 10pv padding then the next column.

Comment: @AustenRobinson - pls clarify from my last question. Thx

Comment: So to clarify, column A would be like just text not clickable.  Column 2 is what the user would be clicking and copying.

Comment: dont see the revised code...but col A is like a label, Column 2 is to be copied.

Comment: Ok, is this what you're after?  Please check updated answer.

Comment: that got me where i want to be except can  column2 be widened and  the container in a whole to fill 90% of the page.  Column 2 will have some lengthy text in it.

Comment: yes sure - sounds like column2 should be a textarea? Do you also want it the text in column2 to look like regular  text? (rather than a text area)?

Comment: both could be text areas.  how it is now is fine but when you click col 2 now it doesnt highlight the text and doesnt say copied.  it did before not sure what was changes.  It also doesnt copy the text.  i just tried the revised code a couple minutes ago

Comment: revised code looks good.  thank you.  just need to expand the container to say 90% and column B text area extended out to about 10px before the end of the container.  have long text to put in col B

Comment: I must be missing something as far as column width goes.  I tried column-width: 20% for the first column and column-width: 80% for the second but they dont adjust accordingly.  Also I need to make the input box in col 2 to adjust to the 80%.  Not sure what else to change.

Comment: sorry, I don't really understand the issue. Sounds like css and this answer was about javascript. If it helped solve your question, please accept it as the answer. As for the css, perhaps you could open up a new question... or paste in a codepen link or something that illustrates the issue.